# React Native - Add a listener to Async Storage value change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, listener

Hello I set the value of AsyncStorage.getItem('authStatus') on LoginPage but the problem is that the Navigator class doesnt respond to value change of AsyncStorage. How to add listener to AsyncStorage.getItem('authStatus')?

```
    export default class Navigator extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { authStatus: ''}
      }
    
    
      async componentDidMount() {
        var authStatus = await AsyncStorage.getItem('authStatus');
       **DOESN'T WORK ->** authStatus.addListener(authStatus => {
          this.setState(this.state.authStatus = authStatus)
        });
        console.log("authStatus =")
        console.log(this.state.authStatus)
        SplashScreen.hide()
      }

 render() {
    return (
      (this.state.authStatus == 'authenticated')
        ?
        this.Home()
        :
        this.AuthStackScreen()
    );
  }
```

Comment: Is the login screen part of auth stack? A stack navigator?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if you are using AsyncStorage in the right way... try something like this:

You can store and retrieve your data like this with AsyncStorage:

```
  const storeData = async (key, value) => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value); 
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const getData = async key => {
    try {
      const data = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
      if (data !== null) {
        console.log(data);
        return data;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

then call getData with the key name like you stored your value wherever you want and set the key to a state value.

Store the value:

```
storeData("authStatus", the value);
```

get the value:

```
  await getData("authStatus") 
    .then((data) => data)
    .then((value) => this.setState({ authStatus: value }))
    .catch((err) => console.log("AsyncStorageErr: " + err));
```

Answer (score 1):

Async Storage is asynchronous, unencrypted, persistent, key-value storage solution for your React Native application. It does not provide any events. It returns a promise.

Refer:
https://react-native-community.github.io/async-storage/docs/usage

In your code "authStatus" may or may not contains a value.

```
try {
    const authStatus = await AsyncStorage.getItem('')
    if(value !== null) {
      // value previously stored
    this.setState({authStatus})
}
```